# How to get URL of new web page when open a new window in Web Browser MFC

Tags: html, visual-c++, mfc

I am developing a Web Browser Program.
This Web Browser is tabbed Browser.
I used ActiveX Control (Internet Web Browser) as Web Browser Control and make this ID as IDC_EXPLORER
In Dialog that places this control I defined EVENTSINK_MAP as follows.

```
BEGIN_EVENTSINK_MAP(CBrowserPane, CDialogEx)
   ON_EVENT(CBrowserPane, IDC_EXPLORER,
       DISPID_BEFORENAVIGATE2,
       _OnBeforeNavigate2,
       VTS_DISPATCH VTS_PVARIANT VTS_PVARIANT VTS_PVARIANT VTS_PVARIANT VTS_PVARIANT VTS_PBOOL)
   ON_EVENT(CBrowserPane, IDC_EXPLORER,
       DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE,
       _OnDocumentComplete,
       VTS_DISPATCH VTS_PVARIANT)
   ON_EVENT(CBrowserPane, IDC_EXPLORER,
       DISPID_DOWNLOADBEGIN,
       _OnDownloadBegin,
       VTS_NONE)
   ON_EVENT(CBrowserPane, IDC_EXPLORER,
       DISPID_PROGRESSCHANGE,
       _OnProgressChange,
       VTS_I4 VTS_I4)
   ON_EVENT(CBrowserPane, IDC_EXPLORER,
       DISPID_DOWNLOADCOMPLETE,
       _OnDownloadComplete,
       VTS_NONE)
   ON_EVENT(CBrowserPane, IDC_EXPLORER,
       DISPID_NAVIGATECOMPLETE2,
       _OnNavigateComplete2,
       VTS_DISPATCH VTS_PVARIANT)
   ON_EVENT(CBrowserPane, IDC_EXPLORER, DISPID_NEWWINDOW,
       _OnNewWindow, VTS_DISPATCH VTS_PBOOL, VTS_I4, VTS_BSTR, VTS_BSTR)
   ON_EVENT(CBrowserPane, IDC_EXPLORER, DISPID_NEWWINDOW2,
       _OnNewWindow2, VTS_DISPATCH VTS_PBOOL)
   ON_EVENT(CBrowserPane, IDC_EXPLORER, DISPID_NEWWINDOW3, 
       _OnNewWindow3, VTS_DISPATCH VTS_PBOOL, VTS_I4, VTS_BSTR, VTS_BSTR)
END_EVENTSINK_MAP()
```

But OnNewWindow2 event is only fired, OnNewWindow3 is not fired.
So I can not get new Url of new page.
Help me!

Answer (score 0):

1. COleControlSite Customization
   In TranslateUrl function, You can get URL of new Page.

```
class CCustomControlSite:public COleControlSite
{
public:
    CCustomControlSite(COleControlContainer *pCnt) :COleControlSite(pCnt) { }

    static WCHAR m_translateUrl[MAX_PATH];
protected:

    DECLARE_INTERFACE_MAP();

BEGIN_INTERFACE_PART(DocHostUIHandler, IDocHostUIHandler)
    STDMETHOD(ShowContextMenu)(/* [in] */ DWORD dwID,
            /* [in] */ POINT __RPC_FAR *ppt,
            /* [in] */ IUnknown __RPC_FAR *pcmdtReserved,
            /* [in] */ IDispatch __RPC_FAR *pdispReserved);
    STDMETHOD(GetHostInfo)( 
            /* [out][in] */ DOCHOSTUIINFO __RPC_FAR *pInfo);
    STDMETHOD(ShowUI)( 
            /* [in] */ DWORD dwID,
            /* [in] */ IOleInPlaceActiveObject __RPC_FAR *pActiveObject,
            /* [in] */ IOleCommandTarget __RPC_FAR *pCommandTarget,
            /* [in] */ IOleInPlaceFrame __RPC_FAR *pFrame,
            /* [in] */ IOleInPlaceUIWindow __RPC_FAR *pDoc);
    STDMETHOD(HideUI)(void);
    STDMETHOD(UpdateUI)(void);
    STDMETHOD(EnableModeless)(/* [in] */ BOOL fEnable);
    STDMETHOD(OnDocWindowActivate)(/* [in] */ BOOL fEnable);
    STDMETHOD(OnFrameWindowActivate)(/* [in] */ BOOL fEnable);
    STDMETHOD(ResizeBorder)( 
            /* [in] */ LPCRECT prcBorder,
            /* [in] */ IOleInPlaceUIWindow __RPC_FAR *pUIWindow,
            /* [in] */ BOOL fRameWindow);
    STDMETHOD(TranslateAccelerator)( 
            /* [in] */ LPMSG lpMsg,
            /* [in] */ const GUID __RPC_FAR *pguidCmdGroup,
            /* [in] */ DWORD nCmdID);
    STDMETHOD(GetOptionKeyPath)( 
            /* [out] */ LPOLESTR __RPC_FAR *pchKey,
            /* [in] */ DWORD dw);
    STDMETHOD(GetDropTarget)(
            /* [in] */ IDropTarget __RPC_FAR *pDropTarget,
            /* [out] */ IDropTarget __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppDropTarget);
    STDMETHOD(GetExternal)( 
            /* [out] */ IDispatch __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppDispatch);
    STDMETHOD(TranslateUrl)( 
            /* [in] */ DWORD dwTranslate,
            /* [in] */ OLECHAR __RPC_FAR *pchURLIn,
            /* [out] */ OLECHAR __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppchURLOut);
    STDMETHOD(FilterDataObject)( 
            /* [in] */ IDataObject __RPC_FAR *pDO,
            /* [out] */ IDataObject __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppDORet);
END_INTERFACE_PART(DocHostUIHandler)

};




BEGIN_INTERFACE_MAP(CCustomControlSite, COleControlSite)
    INTERFACE_PART(CCustomControlSite, IID_IDocHostUIHandler, DocHostUIHandler)
END_INTERFACE_MAP()


ULONG FAR EXPORT  CCustomControlSite::XDocHostUIHandler::AddRef()
{
    METHOD_PROLOGUE(CCustomControlSite, DocHostUIHandler)
    return pThis->ExternalAddRef();
}


ULONG FAR EXPORT  CCustomControlSite::XDocHostUIHandler::Release()
{                            
    METHOD_PROLOGUE(CCustomControlSite, DocHostUIHandler)
    return pThis->ExternalRelease();
}

HRESULT FAR EXPORT  CCustomControlSite::XDocHostUIHandler::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppvObj)
{
    METHOD_PROLOGUE(CCustomControlSite, DocHostUIHandler)
    HRESULT hr = (HRESULT)pThis->ExternalQueryInterface(&riid, ppvObj);
    return hr;
}

// * CImpIDocHostUIHandler::GetHostInfo
// *
// * Purpose: Called at initialization
// *
HRESULT FAR EXPORT  CCustomControlSite::XDocHostUIHandler::GetHostInfo( DOCHOSTUIINFO* pInfo )
{
    METHOD_PROLOGUE(CCustomControlSite, DocHostUIHandler)
    pInfo->dwFlags = DOCHOSTUIFLAG_NO3DBORDER;
    pInfo->dwDoubleClick = DOCHOSTUIDBLCLK_DEFAULT;
    pInfo->dwFlags|= DOCHOSTUIFLAG_USE_WINDOWED_SELECTCONTROL;
    pInfo->dwFlags |= DOCHOSTUIFLAG_OPENNEWWIN;
    return S_OK;
}

// * CImpIDocHostUIHandler::ShowUI
// *
// * Purpose: Called when MSHTML.DLL shows its UI
// *
HRESULT FAR EXPORT  CCustomControlSite::XDocHostUIHandler::ShowUI(
                DWORD dwID, 
                IOleInPlaceActiveObject * /*pActiveObject*/,
                IOleCommandTarget * pCommandTarget,
                IOleInPlaceFrame * /*pFrame*/,
                IOleInPlaceUIWindow * /*pDoc*/)
{
    METHOD_PROLOGUE(CCustomControlSite, DocHostUIHandler)
    // We've already got our own UI in place so just return S_OK
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

// * CImpIDocHostUIHandler::HideUI
// *
// * Purpose: Called when MSHTML.DLL hides its UI
// *
HRESULT FAR EXPORT  CCustomControlSite::XDocHostUIHandler::HideUI(void)
{
    METHOD_PROLOGUE(CCustomControlSite, DocHostUIHandler)
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

// * CImpIDocHostUIHandler::UpdateUI
// *
// * Purpose: Called when MSHTML.DLL updates its UI
// *
HRESULT FAR EXPORT  CCustomControlSite::XDocHostUIHandler::UpdateUI(void)
{
    METHOD_PROLOGUE(CCustomControlSite, DocHostUIHandler)
    // MFC is pretty good about updating it's UI in it's Idle loop so I don't do anything here
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

// * CImpIDocHostUIHandler::EnableModeless
// *
// * Purpose: Called from MSHTML.DLL's IOleInPlaceActiveObject::EnableModeless
// *
HRESULT FAR EXPORT  CCustomControlSite::XDocHostUIHandler::EnableModeless(BOOL fEnable)
{
    METHOD_PROLOGUE(CCustomControlSite, DocHostUIHandler)
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

// * CImpIDocHostUIHandler::OnDocWindowActivate
// *
// * Purpose: Called from MSHTML.DLL's IOleInPlaceActiveObject::OnDocWindowActivate
// *
HRESULT FAR EXPORT  CCustomControlSite::XDocHostUIHandler::OnDocWindowActivate(BOOL /*fActivate*/)
{
    METHOD_PROLOGUE(CCustomControlSite, DocHostUIHandler)
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

// * CImpIDocHostUIHandler::OnFrameWindowActivate
// *
// * Purpose: Called from MSHTML.DLL's IOleInPlaceActiveObject::OnFrameWindowActivate
// *
HRESULT FAR EXPORT  CCustomControlSite::XDocHostUIHandler::OnFrameWindowActivate(BOOL /*fActivate*/)
{
    METHOD_PROLOGUE(CCustomControlSite, DocHostUIHandler)
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

// * CImpIDocHostUIHandler::ResizeBorder
// *
// * Purpose: Called from MSHTML.DLL's IOleInPlaceActiveObject::ResizeBorder
// *
HRESULT FAR EXPORT  CCustomControlSite::XDocHostUIHandler::ResizeBorder(
                LPCRECT /*prcBorder*/, 
                IOleInPlaceUIWindow* /*pUIWindow*/,
                BOOL /*fRameWindow*/)
{
    METHOD_PROLOGUE(CCustomControlSite, DocHostUIHandler)
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

// * CImpIDocHostUIHandler::ShowContextMenu
// *
// * Purpose: Called when MSHTML.DLL would normally display its context menu
// *
HRESULT FAR EXPORT  CCustomControlSite::XDocHostUIHandler::ShowContextMenu(
                DWORD /*dwID*/, 
                POINT* /*pptPosition*/,
                IUnknown* /*pCommandTarget*/,
                IDispatch* /*pDispatchObjectHit*/)
{
    METHOD_PROLOGUE(CCustomControlSite, DocHostUIHandler)
    return S_OK; // We've shown our own context menu. MSHTML.DLL will no longer try to show its own.
}

// * CImpIDocHostUIHandler::TranslateAccelerator
// *
// * Purpose: Called from MSHTML.DLL's TranslateAccelerator routines
// *
HRESULT FAR EXPORT  CCustomControlSite::XDocHostUIHandler::TranslateAccelerator(LPMSG lpMsg,
            /* [in] */ const GUID __RPC_FAR *pguidCmdGroup,
            /* [in] */ DWORD nCmdID)
{
    METHOD_PROLOGUE(CCustomControlSite, DocHostUIHandler)
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

// * CImpIDocHostUIHandler::GetOptionKeyPath
// *
// * Purpose: Called by MSHTML.DLL to find where the host wishes to store 
// *    its options in the registry
// *
HRESULT FAR EXPORT  CCustomControlSite::XDocHostUIHandler::GetOptionKeyPath(BSTR* pbstrKey, DWORD)
{
    METHOD_PROLOGUE(CCustomControlSite, DocHostUIHandler)
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

STDMETHODIMP CCustomControlSite::XDocHostUIHandler::GetDropTarget( 
            /* [in] */ IDropTarget __RPC_FAR *pDropTarget,
            /* [out] */ IDropTarget __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppDropTarget)
{
    METHOD_PROLOGUE(CCustomControlSite, DocHostUIHandler)
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

STDMETHODIMP CCustomControlSite::XDocHostUIHandler::GetExternal( 
            /* [out] */ IDispatch __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppDispatch)
{
    return S_OK;
}

STDMETHODIMP CCustomControlSite::XDocHostUIHandler::TranslateUrl( 
            /* [in] */ DWORD dwTranslate,
            /* [in] */ OLECHAR __RPC_FAR *pchURLIn,
            /* [out] */ OLECHAR __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppchURLOut)
{


   g_strHrefUrl.SetString(pchURLIn);

    METHOD_PROLOGUE(CCustomControlSite, DocHostUIHandler)
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

STDMETHODIMP CCustomControlSite::XDocHostUIHandler::FilterDataObject( 
            /* [in] */ IDataObject __RPC_FAR *pDO,
            /* [out] */ IDataObject __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppDORet)
{
    METHOD_PROLOGUE(CCustomControlSite, DocHostUIHandler)
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}


class CCustomOccManager :public COccManager
{
public:
    CCustomOccManager(){}
    COleControlSite* CreateSite(COleControlContainer* pCtrlCont)
    {
        CCustomControlSite *pSite = new CCustomControlSite(pCtrlCont);
        return pSite;
    }
};
```

2. Register in CreateControlSite of Dialog.

```
BOOL CBrowserPane::CreateControlSite(COleControlContainer* pContainer, COleControlSite** ppSite, UINT nID, REFCLSID clsid)
{
    ASSERT(ppSite != NULL);
    m_pControlSite = new CCustomControlSite(pContainer);
    *ppSite = m_pControlSite;
    return TRUE;
}
```